# ¿Cómo cambiar la url del registro de usuarios en wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

soy nuevo en esto de wordpress, he logrado modificar mi url de ingreso (login) con ayuda de plugins, asi que mi url de login es `https://www.midominio.net/login/` y bueno mi url de registro de usuarios es `https://www.midominio.net/login/?action=register` que es exactamente lo que quiero cambiar el `/login/?action=register` por una sola palabra como `registro`. 
Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Podés probar con el plugin [Custom login Url](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-login-url/) que modifica el url del login como vos necesitas.